# Disallow intercept touches of Listview while using its Child MapView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mapview, ontouchlistener, intercept

I want to **disallow intercept touches of Listview** while Moving, zooming & pinch in MapView which is inside Listview's Header View.

I have one **ListView** contains all stores. I have set one **List View Header** as another layout xml and adding it to Main ListView.

**ListView Header**

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapViewStores"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

**StoreList.java** which extends **Fragment**

```
MapView mapView;        //Map View
GoogleMap mapStoreList; //For Markers on Map

listViewStoreData.addHeaderView(headerViewForStoreList);

mapView = (MapView) headerViewForStoreList
                .findViewById(R.id.mapViewStores);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (mapView != null) {
    mapStoreList = mapView.getMap();
    mapStoreList.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mapStoreList.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 13);
    mapStoreList.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

I have set code for disallow for Intercept touches of parent view

```
mapStoreList.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break
            }

            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, it's not working.

But when set `OnTouchListener` to `ListView` object, it'll log events.

```
listViewStoreData.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                Log.e("MotionEvent", "Move");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.e("MotionEvent", "Up");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.e("MotionEvent", "Down");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.e("MotionEvent", "Cancel");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK:
                Log.e("MotionEvent", "Pointer Index Mask");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT:
                Log.e("MotionEvent", "Pointer Index Shift");
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

So, how do I overcome from this situation ?
 Is there any possibility that we cannot get '`OnTouchListerner`' for `ListView`'s Child -> Header View's Child -> `MapView` ??

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any solution @Imanan

Answer (score 5):

Override `dispatchTouchEvent()` and stop the listview from intercepting touch events on ACTION_DOWN.  In my case, I implemented it in the ViewGroup containing my MapView, but it'd probably work fine if you extended MapView instead as well.  The only thing you need is a reference to the ListView the MapView resides within.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(final MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (motionEvent.getActionMasked()) {
        // Pressed on map: stop listview from scrolling
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            break;

        // Released on map or cancelled: listview can be normal again
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            listView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            break;
    }

    // Process event as normal. If listview was disallowed touch events, the map will process the event.
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}
```

This would likely work with most/all containers that have a scrolling mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for this! I can confirm that this works from a MapView subclass as well. Simply use ```getParent()``` in place of ```listView```.